# why bother to find the frozen indices of polar code

Tags: coding-theory

Can someone explains to me why the indices of frozen bit in polar code are not in the counting order from index 0? For example, for N = 8 and k = 4 (information bit), the indices of frozen bit is 0,1,2,4 but not 0,1,2,3?

["Polarization and Polar Codes"](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Esasoglu/0100000041.pdf), by Eren Sasoglu, explains the idea of the channel polarization beautifully. However, according to its explanation, the channel with higher indices normally will have higher capacity and those with smaller indices have smaller capacity. Therefore, why we still need to calculate the Bhattacharyya parameter one by one for each channel to determine their reliability and select those with lower reliability as our frozen bit? Instead, I was wondering that we can just select the frozen bit in a counting order starting from 0.

Comment: Frozen bit in polar code: are we in Siberia ? What is the meaning of these terms ?

Comment: Frozen bits are referred to those bits which are preset before being transmitted (and known to receiver).

Comment: Warm thanks :) ...

Comment: The document is 125 pages long, can you give us the page number or section number you are refering?

Answer (score 1):

Polar coding is a randomized coding algorithm, and crucially depends on this randomization.

Thus you do need to calculate the Bhattacharya for each bit.

To clarify, please see the Polar Codes inventor Erdal Arikan's [slides](https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/2689/slidesarikan.pdf) from the Simons Institute tutorial. Specifically slide 59 and the few following it. The quality of the channels is NOT monotone, you are just looking at a tiny 8x8 example. This is why Bhattacharya coefficients must be computed.

[image: 16x16 polarization for BEC(1/2)]

[image: 512x512 polarization for BEC(1/2)]

Comment: Let says we have 4 inputs U0,U1,U2,U3,U4,U5,U6,U7. U0 is corresponding to H---. While the others follow: U1 <-> H--+; U2 <-> H-+-; U3 <-> H-++; U4 <-> H+--; U5 <-> H+-+; U6 <-> H++-; U7 <-> H++. Note that '-' indicates the degrade of the channel capacity while '+' indicates the improve of the channel channel. Thus, the more `-' the worst of the channel. Therefore, that's why our sequence is following the order 0,1,2,4,3,5,6,7.

Comment: There why don't we just look at the binary representation of the indices and figure out the sequence instead of calculating the Bhattacharya parameters? Can you give me an example of showing that my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Sorry the first comment has a typo. It should be 8 inputs

Comment: thank for your help. Its clears up my doubts!